# Script .py reading fine but not after building with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When i run setup.py as a script i have no issues reading a parameter file.
When i build with pyinstaller and run the same script as a .exe i receive the below error.

```
     >setup.exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 106, in <module>
    param_file_info = paramsfx.extract_param_file_info(param_text)
  File "app\paramsfx.py", line 64, in extract_param_file_info
    s_n = re.search(rc_n, param_file_text)
  File "c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
[21776] Failed to execute script setup
```

i have read up on other posts how to resolve this error however before changing the code (that is working fine as a script) i wanted to see if anyone had any thoughts as to why it read the parameter differently as a .exe.

Comment: What flags did you use with `pyinstaller`? `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` seems like an error in the actual python file

Comment: pyinstaller.exe --onefile setup.spec --hidden-import=sqlite3 --additional-hooks-dir="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks"  The .py file is fine because when i run the setup.py in Spyder it all works fine with no error.

Comment: For anyone who runs into this issue.  Spyder was just ignoring the error depending on your settings.  When you build into an exe it will throw an exception.  Changing to 'cp1252' encoding solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just from looking at this output and not the code I noticed this:
"TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"

If this is true, I would recommend doing some python type conversion. Here is a link to help you out
https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_numbers_convert

Because I don't know how your code is structured, choosing which form of conversion you choose may affect your results so please be careful with that.

I hope my explanation could have provided some use to you.

Comment: OK thanks i will look at the link you provided.  As i was saying the actual .py works fine when run in Spyder so it seems something that is being linked when i build with pyinstaller is what is causing the issue.